# How can I add Multi class binding in Vue2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I faced one problem when I put multi-class `binding` in Vue2.

```
<div class="list-item clearfix" v-on:click="selectItem(trail)" :class="popupMode ? 'popup' : ''">
```

Here `popupMode` is props and I'd like to add one more `class` `binding` when I select the `Item(click function:`selectItem()`)`.

For example, similar to `selected`.

This `class` is defined. How can I manage this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update HTML class bind like:

```
v-bind:class="{ popup: popupMode, selected: isSelected }"
```

where `isSelected` is a new prop like `popupMode`. On element click when `selectItem` method is called, set the bool `isSelected` prop to `true` and you will be able to see `selected` class after that.

**JS:**

```
data: {
    popupMode: true,
    isSelected: false
},
methods: {
    selectItem() {
        this.isSelected= true;
    }
}
```

For more info check this: [Binding HTML Classes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-HTML-Classes)

Comment: @palasH,
it works for me. but I have a problem to use this. for example, there are 5 items, when I chick the first item, it'll be changed to grey color. then when I next(second) item, I'd like to change the first item to original status and second item is be changed to grey color too. In this case, how can I do it?

Comment: You can create a `default` class with black or any other color which you want to set as original status color. then update bind class for all like: `{ popup: popupMode, selected: isSelected, default: !isSelected }`. This way only one will be set as `selected` class at one time.

Comment: default class is `class="list-item clearfix"`. in this case, how can I call it?

Comment: `{ 'list-item': !isSelected, 'clearfix': !isSelected }`

Comment: well... it doesn't work for me. I'd like to discuss more details about this. where can we do it?

Comment: I think you will get much more responses from other users too if you create a small demo for your use case and explain what the issue is currently as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:

```
{ active: isActive, 'text-danger': hasError }
```

Don't forget place `isActive` and `hasError` in `data` (in this case).
I hope this help's.